# i'm trying to learn methods for the first time but i am just getting an error when trying to compile

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to set up method code but keep getting an error. I've made sure I have the right braces where they are supposed to be. And all the code is inside the class so I'm really confused. It's probably a simple fix but I can't see it.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumbersFunctions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        double x, y, z;
        System.out.println("Please input 3 numbers");
        x = keyboard.nextDouble();
        y = keyboard.nextDouble();
        z = keyboard.nextDouble();

        public double smallest(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            if (x < y && x < z) {
                System.out.println(x);
            } else if (y < z) {
                System.out.println(y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
  Numbers.java:10: error: illegal start of expression
  public double smallest(double x, double y, double z) {
  ^
  Numbers.java:19: error: class, interface, or enum expected
  }
```

Comment: You can't declare method inside of a method. You need to declare it outside of main method.

Comment: So then how do i get the user input that i asked for? cause i have 5 methods i need to use

Comment: You pass them in method arguments when calling it. min = smallest(x, y, z) - to use it that way you need to add return statement instead of print (considering your method is public double, so it returns some double) and probably make it static unless you want to create an instance of class first. In other words, just go read any tutorial on java, there are lots of good examples in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjusting your code a bit, that's how it works ...

```
 public class NumbersFunctions {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   double x, y, z;
   System.out.println("Please input 3 numbers");
   x = keyboard.nextDouble();
   y = keyboard.nextDouble();
   z = keyboard.nextDouble();

   smallest(x, y, z);

}  

public static void smallest(double x, double y, double z)
{

   if(x < y && x < z){
     System.out.println(x);
   }else if(y < z){
     System.out.println(y);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me understand the problem and how to use it. I know this was very simple but i was looking and couldn't find what i was looking for to help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to write it. You have 2 methods inside a class. The main() will call the smallest() method.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class NumbersFunctions
{

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    double x, y, z;
    System.out.println("Please input 3 numbers");
    x = keyboard.nextDouble();
    y = keyboard.nextDouble();
    z = keyboard.nextDouble();

    smallest(x, y, z);
    //System.out.println(smallest(x, y, z));

  }

  public static void smallest(double x, double y, double z)
// public Double smallest(double x, double y, double z)
  {

    if(x < y && x < z){
      System.out.println(x);
      //return(x);
    }
    else if(y < z){
      System.out.println(y);
      //return(y);
  }
    else {
      System.out.println(z);
      //return(z);

}   
}
```

Comment: Will not compile. Cannot  call instance method from a static method.

Comment: And although this is allowed, it is usually considered better form to invoke static methods using the class name, i.e., `NumbersFunctions.smallest(...);` rather than just `smallest(...);`

Comment: I didn't see the return. should be static void. edited.